# Is there any work around for RF4 dataScroller pages facet?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am trying to upgrade RF3 to RF4 and JSF1.2 to JSF 2. So while looking into the , pages, pageIndexVar attributes were removed from richFaces 4! i came to know that in rich faces 4, pages facet was not implemented. But in my application i need to show total number of rows and current page number! sample code which is in RF3 is:

```
<rich:dataScroller id="dataScrollerTop" for="richTableID"
                               pagesVar="pages" pageIndexVar="current"
                               fastControls="hide"  renderIfSinglePage="false" />
```

**pagesVar="pages" pageIndexVar="current"** these attributes were removed in RF4. Is there any work around to show total number of pages and current page? 
If yes please guide me by suggesting any tutorial or any hints!

One more Question: Can we create pages facet for UIComponent to show number of rows? If yes, please suggest me! 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by implementing the customDataScroller with renderer! 
In the doEncodeEnd(..) method of Renderer class, i have added mu pagination. Now the UI of the dataScroller is being displayed according to my requirement. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use data model class **YourDataModel extends ExtendedDataModel implements Arrangeable** and

```
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {... }
```

use method getRowCount for row count.

Current page is stored automatically in dataScroller. You can add

```
    private int pageIndex = 1;
```

in your data model class and use it when you need. For setup it in dataScroller see example (**page** attribute):

```
<rich:dataScroller id="chTableDataScroller"
renderIfSinglePage="false"
page="#{chAction.clients.pageIndex}"
stepControls="show"
fastControls="#{chAction.clients.rowCount/referenceData.recordsPerPage > 10 ? 'show' : 'hide'}"
fastStep="10" />
```

After implementation the data model countOfPages = countOfRows / rowsPerPage. RowsPerPage is defined in datatable in **rows** attribute:

```
<rich:dataTable rows="#{referenceData.recordsPerPage}"
value="#{chAction.clients}" var="res" >
```

Comment: Thanks you for answering. but I implemented multiple dataModels in rich:tabs so all tabs had common pageinationfacets.xtml like below:

Comment: Edited the question please review it once. if you are not clear with the content which i provided please let me know what sort of thing you want to analyze. Thanks in advance!